# Post tweet on friends wall

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I am using https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine to post tweet on user wall. I am using this because i want to support minimum OS 4.3. I want to know how to post tweet on friends wall. There is direct Message in the "MGTwitterEngine". but I want to post of friends wall rather than text message.

Comment: Have you ever used Twitter? It doesn't work the way you seem to think it works -- it's not based on making posts "on" other users.

Comment: @duskWuff Thanks for your reply. YES I have used twitter.Can you point me to twitter official page where it says that you cannot post on user wall. I want to set the status or post something on XYZ user wall. Yes it can Open up the twitter and go to XYZ user and from left side panel you will see a text field click on it and compose the tweet for that user and click send.

Comment: Do you want to tweet user by @user_name??? Or you mean something else?

Comment: @user1799469 That posts an `@` message. It does not appear on the target user's tweets; it appears in your own.

Comment: @Atif I want to tweet user by name.